# Convenciones de Cake PHP 3.5

Tags: php, cakephp, backend

quisiera saber si hay una posibilidad de crear un controlador en cakePHP 3.5.x que pueda usar una tabla que no se asocie con su nombre, por ejemplo si quiero seguir sus convenciones creo una tabla en plural de alumnos "studens" por lo que el entity y table de CAKE debe seguir sus convenciones sigular/plural, pero el controlador lo quiero llamar alumnos para que la ruta sea entendible para personas de habla hispana, ya que el sistema sera para ellos, esto manda un error debido a que para esos datos cake espera que nombre al controlador studens, hay alguna forma de llamarlo alumnos y tener acceso a el modelo de students.

Saludos y gracias

Comment: Se me ocurre que puedes manejarlo internamente con redirecciones desde el punto de entrada de la API. O sea, recoges todo en el servidor y rediriges las peticiones. El usuario en castallenao escribirá `api/alumnos/...`  en el navegador, pero tú internamente haces lo mismo que si hubiese escrito `students`. Así te evitas el tener que mantener dos versiones de la API, con carpetas duplicadas para cada una, lo cual se complicaría si se tratase de más idiomas.

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres cambiar la ruta puedes hacerlo desde `config/routes.php`, dentro del bloque donde se definen las rutas puedes poner tu configuración, de esta manera puedes seguir las convenciones y tener la ruta que necesitas

```
Router::scope('/', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
    // Código
    $routes->connect('/alumnos', ['controller' => 'Students', 'action' => 'index']);
});
```

Te sugiero que leas un poco acerca del 'Routing' en la [documentación](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html) (inglés)

Answer (score 0):

Buenas, también puedes crear tus tablas en español, que no lo sugiero y luego en tu archivo **config/bootstrap.php** añades las reglas con las clase estática Inflector.

[Inflectores personalizados](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/inflector.html#loading-custom-inflections)

También puedes coger esta herramienta para salir de dudas cuando vayas a generar tus tablas.

[herramienta de inflectores](https://inflector.cakephp.org/alumno)

Pero la mejor forma es creando las rutas personalizadas como te mencionó [Kacos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/22721/kacos)